# Import Fields from One Model into another Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, console, export

I am consolidating several models (ideas, questions, etc...) into one topic model in the console and I thought something like this might work:

```
Question.find_each do |q|
  t = Topic.new
  t.create(:title=q.title, :description=q.description, :kind=”Question”)
end
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
 SyntaxError: (irb):24: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')'
 t.create(:title=q.title,:description=q.description,:kind='question')
```

Wondering if anyone has ever tried transferring data between models like this and if there's a "right" way to do it.

[edit]
This works:

```
Question.find_each do |q|  
@qt=q.title  
@qd=q.description  
@q=‘Question’  
@ca=q.created_at  
@ui=q.user.id  
@uvt=q.user_votes_total  
Topic.create!({:title => @qt, :description => [@qd], :kind => @q, :created_at=>@ca, :user_id=>@ui, :user_votes_total=>@uvt })  
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `=` with `=>`

```
t.create(:title => q.title, :description => q.description, :kind => 'Question')
```

Comment: Thanks! I posted the final version that works in the question so that someone else might find the answer when their brain stops working :)